# Org-table: is it possible to have automatic line wrapping inside org-tables?

Tags: org-table

Org-table has a very convenient property, it expands the width of a table column if needed to show all your text in a cell. Alternatively, you can set a fixed width for a table column and let your text be truncated (the not-shown text representet as ...).

However, sometimes it would have been practical to apply a fixed width on a table column, and instead of showing the text truncated, showing it as multiple lines automatically wrapped inside the table cell (thererby expanding the number of lines in the row of the table where your table cell is located).

Is autmoatic line wrapping possible within an org table?

Comment: After trying `tabel.el`, as well as two MacOS apps called TableFlip and MarkupTable, I decided the best solution for me is to simply edit the table in Excel or Google Sheets, then copy-paste the contents onto this site to convert to org-mode table format: https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is autmoatic line wrapping possible within an org table?

No. The limitation apparently comes from the `field` in a column has to be on a single line. I don't know if such limitations can be removed. However, there are two other related techniques for wrapping in cells that you may have already seen in the manual: `narrow columns` and `C-c C-q` to `wrap several fields in a column`. Both have their uses.