# How to <return> in a org table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Instead of

```
|   | some value         |
|-- +--------------------|
| a | aaaaaaaa           |
|---+--------------------|
| b | bbbbbbb bbbbbbbbb  |
|---+--------------------|
```

I want

```
|   | some value         |
|-- +--------------------|
| a | aaaaaaaa           |
|---+--------------------|
| b | bbbbbbb            |
|   | bbbbbbbbb          |
|---+--------------------|
```

because sometimes the table is too long to display and I have to use scroll commands or bol/eol to view the table. Also I have no idea about how to get it nicely export to LaTeX. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does M-<RET>  (org-table-wrap-region) work for you?

Comment: @RomanSusi It does! I've tried <RET>, C-<RET>, `newline`, `newline-and-indent` etc. but this one! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to make text to wrap by pressing M-, take a look at the [table editor docs](http://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-table-editor.html)

As for export into latex, M-x org-table-export and specifying file name with .tex extension should work.

Here is what I got for your second table:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
 & some value\\
\hline
a & aaaaaaaa\\
\hline
b & bbbbbbb\\
 & bbbbbbbbb\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

It adds an explicit break though.

Please, see also answers for this question: [Org-table: is it possible to have automatic line wrapping inside org-tables?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22318/org-table-is-it-possible-to-have-automatic-line-wrapping-inside-org-tables)